# Calcular idade em laravel

Tags: laravel

Quero calcular a idade atravès da data de nascimento, vou deixar o processamento no banco, sou novo em Laravel e não estou conseguindo executar a seguinte query:

```
SELECT YEAR(FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(NOW())-TO_DAYS(dataNascimento))) AS idade FROM pessoas
```

meu codigo está mais ou menos assim:

```
return view('pessoas.grafico-idade', array('pessoas' => Pessoa::select('pessoa')->select('dataNascimento','YEAR(FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(NOW())-TO_DAYS(dataNascimento))) AS idade')->get()));
```

Comment: @VirgilioNovic Já olhei essa quest antes de abrir esta pergunta, eu estou tentando fazer em Laravel.
Mas de toda forma já consegui aqui resolver.

Answer (score 1):

tente algo como:

```
return view('pessoas.grafico-idade', array('pessoas' => Pessoa::select('pessoa')->select('dataNascimento',DB::raw('YEAR(FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(NOW())-TO_DAYS(dataNascimento))) AS idade'))->get()));
```

Obs: isso irá acusar um novo erro, vai falar que o objeto DB não foi instanciado.
Nesse caso você coloca esse trecho no começo do seu código:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
```